# Creating headers (and footers) in the middle of returned query data with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of data that I want to turn from raw data into something a little 'prettier' and organized to look at.
The data consists of payments made (3 columns: Name, payment amount, and date of payment).

I'd like to present the data so that for each group of dates that are the same there is a header above those rows with the date itself so the user can see these rows of dates are for say 1/14/2023.

Then the next set of rows for say 1/15/2023 would have the header 1/15/2023.

Please see the attached image.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5kxO.jpg)

In columns A - C is the raw data and I don't know how many and which dates there will be a priori. In columns E-G is the desired output.

You can see I'd also like if possible a footer that sums the totals for that day.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? The ideal solution would be such that you could paste raw data into columns A-C and then the data shows up in columns E-G formatted. I'm hoping there's a design pattern for this type of thing before I cobble together a solution.

I've implemented something through Apps Script, but am more interested in learning if there's a way through the formulas provided in Sheets.

I can see this possibly being done with temp/work tables, but am wondering if this is a common problem/solution and would love to get pointed in the right direction. I'm a programmer and have been using sheets for about a year and can write queries and filters and do lots of things but want to learn the right way and not always just do something the first way that pops into my head that works.

Comment: Welcome! Look into Pivot Tables, with that kind of format you're looking it's probably the best solution

Comment: @Martín - Awesome idea. I tried the pivot table approach and it got me very close to what I wanted. It did the footers perfectly, and the headers were just slightly different. Your idea is the simplest to implement and is an awesome suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this formula along with a bit of conditional formatting to get the expected output.

***Headsup***: Set Columns E, F to ***DATE Type*** formatting

```
=LAMBDA(czx,MAP(INDEX(czx,,1),INDEX(czx,,2),INDEX(czx,,3),LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,{ax,IF(ISNUMBER(ax),{"",""},IF(ax="TOTALS",{"",cx},IF(LEN(ax),{bx,cx})))})))(SORT(LAMBDA(ax,FILTER(ax,INDEX(ax,,1)<>""))({BYROW(UNIQUE(B:B),LAMBDA(bx,IF(bx="",,{bx,bx,0})));A:C;BYROW(UNIQUE(B:B),LAMBDA(bx,IF(bx="",,{"TOTALS",bx,SUMIF(B:B,bx,C:C)})))}),2,1))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is formula wizardry! Thanks so much! The LAMBDA is totally new to me and will be really helpful moving forward. For ages I've wished there were a way to create variables so I didn't have to repeat a long expression in, e.g. an IF condition and one of its two results. It took a while for me to digest this but I was able to break it down and understand the approach: 1. Add the headers and footers based on unique dates under the data 2. Sort so that the headers and footers are correctly located. 3. Remove unwanted text...

Comment: cool... and that's pretty much the breakup of the formula:)