# Creating a recursive Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So here's what I'm trying to do: I have a query formula on Sheet 3 that pulls data from Sheet 2, based on values from Sheet 1. Then I add a header/footer row before/after the data. What I want to do is re-run that formula block for each row in Sheet 1 Column A that has data, but in each instance increase the value of the row by one, and stop when the rows are empty.

Can't just do it with a single query with grouping/ordering, because of the headers/footers.

So far, I've got this (just the first two cycles):

```
`={ 
{Sheet1!A3,"","","","","",""}; 
query(Sheet2!D:S, "select D,F,H,J,N,P,R where J contains '"&Sheet1!A3&"' order by F",0);
{"TOTAL","","","","","",Sheet1!B3}; 
{"","","","","","",""}; 
{Sheet1!A4,"","","","","",""}; 
query(Sheet2!D:S, "select D,F,H,J,N,P,R where J contains '"&Sheet1!A4&"' order by F",0); {"TOTAL","","","","","",Sheet1!B4} 
}`
```

The result is this:
screenshot

[image]

It works great, but it'll be super tedious to repeat dozens of times.

This is pushing against the bounds of my formula knowledge, so I need someone to point me in the right direction. Is this handled with some sort of INDEX or VLOOKUP or ARRAY function? Or would it require a script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75120823/5479575 Here's a similar Q&A you can have a look at...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this REDUCE option and let me know if it returns your desired result?

```
=REDUCE({"","","","","","",""},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A3:A)),LAMBDA(a,b,{a; 
{INDEX(Sheet1!A3:A,b),"","","","","",""}; 
query(Sheet2!D:S, "select D,F,H,J,N,P,R where J contains '"&INDEX(Sheet1!A3:A,b)&"' order by F",0);
{"TOTAL","","","","","",INDEX(Sheet1!B3:B,b)}}))
```

You may change the first argument all those "","","" with the headers from your table. Let me know if it's useful